# Javascript if short notation

Tags: javascript

I was surfing on the web in search of a shorthand Javascript notation for an if-statement. ONLY the if, not the else. My question: does it exist? eg:

```
(i === 0) ? onlyMyTrueValue;
```

The only snippet I seem to find is this one:

```
(i === 0) ? myTrueValue : myFalseValue;
```

Comment: Google short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: The shorthand way to write an `if` statement is `if(i===0)somevar=someval;` but you should let a JS minifier handle that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
(i === 0) && onlyMyTrueValue;
```

The right hand side of the above statement will execute only if the left hand side passes.

Comment: This feature of JavaScript has spoiled me so much.

Comment: Wish I would've known about this, +1

Comment: @ajp15243 - I can't deny my indulgence either.. ;-)

Comment: But that expression won't return `onlyMyTrueValue`  if it's not a boolean value.

Comment: Actually it will return it as is, whatever its type is, if the first expression evaluates to `truthy` value.

Comment: Yes, it will return the actual value (not the boolean equivalent) of the RHS of the `&&`, as long as the LHS is truthy.

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, you are right! Didn't think so, but I tested!

Comment: this makes for code that is hard to read. at least comment it.

Comment: `(1 === 1) && "Hello"` returns `"Hello"` - Just to get the point across.. ;-)

Comment: Yep. It returns `false` otherwise. But I guess he didn't care about a  `false` evaluation of the conditional part.

Comment: @acdcjunior - Yes, thats right. But i guess thats insignificant in this particular case.

Answer (score 11):

You could do `(i === 0) && onlyMyTrueValue;`, but you shouldn't, for readability sake.

Compare your original:

```
(i === 0) ? onlyMyTrueValue;
```

And plain old if:

```
if (i === 0) onlyMyTrueValue;
```

That's only one more character, and an identical number of characters to the `&&` method. Go with the readable choice.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that readability is king. Although I find a situation like `var foo = bar || [];` is helpful for assigning default values if the value you are trying to assign (`bar`) is something like `undefined` or `null` that you want to filter out.

Comment: Readability is **the most** important thing when reading code branching 99.9% of the time. The short-circuit way is less readable. If you're worried about file size run your code through the closure compiler first, it'll minify ifs to short-circuits.

Comment: @nathanhayfield He was just quoting the OP and comparing with that hypothetical syntax.